# scraping body of a page using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Scraping body of a page using php and limiting the character length being crawled to like 100.
How can i achieve that. The code below scrap or crawl the body of a page and get its content but also scrap or crawl both the body of the page and its source code. Please how can i scrap/ crawl only the text on the body of a page and limit the character to like 100 before outputting

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0); 

echo $body->textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$body_output = substr($body->textContent, 0, 100);
echo $body_output;
```